# How to use Magentor gem

Tags: ruby, magento

I am trying to use the [Magentor](https://github.com/pstuteville/magentor) gem. The documentation is very weak. I succeeded in calling `Magento::Category.info(1)`.

But I failed to call `Magento::Category.create(args)`.

The method definition is like the following.

```
  # catalog_category.create
  # Create new category and return its id.
  # 
  # Return: int
  # 
  # Arguments:
  # 
  # int $parentId - ID of parent category
  # array $categoryData - category data ( array(’attribute_code’⇒‘attribute_value’ )
  # mixed $storeView - store view ID or code (optional)
  def create(attributes)
    id = commit("create", attributes)
    record = new(attributes)
    record.id = id
    record
  end
```

Here's what I tried.(parent id is 1)

```
args = [1, {:name => 'Cars', :description => 'Great Cars', :is_active => '1', :url_key => 'cars'}]
category_id = Magento::Category.create(args)

exception: 1 -> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Can anybody provide an example of calling the method?

Comment: Looks like an interesting project. The generated rdocs actually look much better than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the gem developer and got the following reply. A nice guy.

---

Hi Sam,

Sorry about the sparse documentation. We had created this library very quickly and only used a small subset of the api in the project we were working on.

It looks like the call for create in the library does not pass through data correctly. Here is a workaround:

```
parent_id = 1
attributes =  {
  :url_key=>"cars", 
  :description=>"Great Cars", 
  :name=>"Cars", 
  :is_active=>"1", 
  :available_sort_by => "Name", 
  :default_sort_by => "Name",
  :include_in_menu => '1'
}
category_id = Magento::Category.commit("create", parent_id, attributes)
```

I'll also commit a fix to github that takes the parent_id correctly.

Thanks,
-preston